# I want to get phones data to drop-down list in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to get phones data to drop-down list in Meteor.I am using Mongodb.I tried something but it doesnt work

> phones.js

```
Template.Phones.helpers({
  getPhones: function(){
    return Phone.find({});
  }
});
```

> show.html

```
<select class="form-control" name="aracsec" size="1" style="height:40px; width:290px; float:right" id="aracsec">
    {{#each getPhones}}
          <option value="{{userphone}}">{{userphone}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
```

Comment: This question needs more info: right now there is nothing that looks wrong. Describe how "it doesn't work" in greater detail, post error messages, give more context please.

Comment: I didn't get any error,just  return empty <option value> .when I write it to console,I can see data.